# Where/when is the update for Firefox to version 37..?

Tags: updates, firefox, 14.10

I checked with Synaptic Package Manager and the latest is 36.0.1+.....

37 was released in March.

Comment: 14.10 repos already have v37 (http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=utopic-updates&searchon=names&keywords=firefox) - have you got firefox pinned in synaptic to v36?  Any package errors ? (run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`)

Comment: Did you run sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade ?

Comment: Yes, I regularly update my six Linux systems. For ubuntu use sudo apt-get dist-upgrade and tried  sudo apt-get upgrade... .. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see from the [full publishing history for Firefox in Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+publishinghistory) that v37 has been available in every supported version of Ubuntu in the hours following 2015-04-07 09:31:51 UTC.

In supported versions of Ubuntu (Precise, Trusty and Utopic) it's sitting in both the updates and security repos. In Vivid (which is still just about in development, it's just in the main repo.

You either...

- ... have a stale package list (`sudo apt-get update` or click Update in your package manager)
- ... are subscribed to a [seriously] stale mirror of the updates/security repos. Switch to another using the Software Sources dialogue.
- ... aren't using a supported version of Ubuntu (Precise, Trusty, Utopic or Vivid). Upgrade.

Comment: Using http://mirrors.arpnetworks.com/Ubuntu, switched to http://mirrors.us.kernel.org, and got...
59 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 152 MB of archives.
Obviously a seriously stale mirror..!..!..!
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you run in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

this may install the newest version 37 of FireFox if the upgrade was hold back/could not have been installed because it has different dependencies in comparison to version 36.

Comment: Actually this doesn't install Firefox

Comment: @Lucio It does not _install_ FireFox, but it might do the upgrade from 36 to 37!

Comment: Don't you need to do `apt-get upgrade` to do so?

Comment: @Lucio `apt-get distupgrade` includes `upgrade`, but is also capable of intelligently handling changing dependencies (another lib has to be installed or one gets removed for example). The normal `upgrade` just holds the update back in this case.

Comment: This is my regular way of upgrading ubuntu... .. .

Answer (score 1):

It is available for Ubuntu 14.10:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/37.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.14.10.1

Do you have the security or updates sources enabled in the "Software & Updates" preference app (look in Updates tab)?

Comment: Yes they are selected.

Answer (score 0):

Click the reload button in the upper left hand corner to update your listing in Synaptic Package Manager:

[image: SynapticPackageManager]

If all else fails, try changing your server in software sources: Open Software & Updates, choose Download From as shown:

[image: S&U]

And choose Other and then choose a server near you shown as close to being being up to date as possible in [this listing](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors)

Comment: My synaptic shows only version 36...