# How do you report a seriously outdated repository mirror?

Tags: updates, 14.10, repository, software-sources, mirrors

Using mirrors.arpnetworks.com/Ubuntu, switched to mirrors.us.kernel.org, and got... 
59 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 
Need to get 152 MB of archives.

http://mirrors.arpnetworks.com is in the list of mirrors on "Software & Updates"

Comment: The stimulus for this question can be seen at http://askubuntu.com/questions/608948/where-when-is-the-update-for-firefox-to-version-37

Answer (score 2):

From https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mirrors#Communication

> if you have questions, email us at mirrors@ubuntu.com.

You could also try posting to the Mirrors mailing list at https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-mirrors

Comment: I have sent an email to: mirrors@ubuntu.com